# How can I write multiple IF conditions in IEnumarable

Tags: c#

Please give me a hint what return type I mention:

```
public IEnumerable<EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER> CustomerType(int Cust)
{
    if (Cust == 1)
    {
        var x = (from n in db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER
                 where n.BUSINESSTYPE_ID == 1
                 select n).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        var x = from n in db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER
                select n;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Here if I provide return x I'm getting an error.

Comment: `x` is `undefined` by the looks of it

Comment: @marc_s   My x is not Comming

Comment: What's wrong with `return (from n in db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER
                 where Cust != 1 || n.BUSINESSTYPE_ID == 1
                 select n).ToList();`?

Comment: Just declare `x` outside the if-statements as `IEnumerable<EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER>` or use `return (from...)`.

Comment: remove the .ToList in the IF statement, and declare x on top of the whole statemant as IEnumerable<EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER>.

Comment: I **strongly doubt** this is the error message you're getting - please post the **concrete and complete** error message you get, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out, x was not defined at a level that the return statement could reach. So we've just moved that out into it's own definition and ensured that the else block .ToList()'s the result. hope this helps.

```
public List<EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER> CustomerType(int Cust)
{
    List<EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER> x = new List<EMS_BUSINESS_TYPE>();
    if (Cust == 1)
    {
        x = (from n in db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER
                where n.BUSINESSTYPE_ID == 1
                select n).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        x = (from n in db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER
                select n).ToList();
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: no need to write `new List<...>` as the variable is allways initialized in all branches.

Comment: I suggest to keep the IEnumerable as return type and not ".ToList()" on x assignment.

Comment: Could the else be simplified to `x = db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER.ToList();`?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest an approach like below.

`x` is set to one of the cases, and then if the `if` condition is met it is reassigned with the specific results for that scenario (i.e. business type of 1).

```
public IEnumerable<EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER> CustomerType(int Cust)
{
    var x = db.EMS_BUSINESSTYPE_MASTER; // no need for the `select`

    if (Cust == 1)
    {
        x = x.Where(z => z.BUSINESSTYPE_ID == 1);
    }

    return x;
}
```

The reason this helps is due to how scoping works in C#. Outside of the `if` and `else` the `x` (in your original code) effectively didn't exist. By declaring the `x` variable **before** the `if` it exists even outside of the `if`.

Comment: @miWills how can i write else condition

Comment: You don't need the else condition in this scenario @coocooo (since my code **before** the `if` is the same as your current `else`). But if you did need it (for some other scenario) you'd do exactly like the `if` - you'd assign to `x` in the same way.